# trying to swap my tkinter screen and it just doesn't work,

Tags: tkinter

Trying to code a easy frame swap but it doesn't work the way I want it to, how do i make it swap the `tkinter` screens

I tried using this giant block of code due to not understanding coding the best, I haven't used classes, `init` due to not understanding how they work
the code basically is supposed to count each time u click the step button, print that to a file and repeat so those steps are recorded
I want to swap screens to have a start and a settings screen so it can look a bit nicer

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import Frame
file2 = open('datasave.txt','r')
walked = file2.read()
steps = int(walked)  

def clicked():
    global steps
    steps = steps + 1
    screen.configure(text=('steps=', steps))
    file1 = open('datasave.txt','w')
    file1.write(str(steps))
def raise_frame(Frame):
    Frame.tkraise()
    
    
#making the screen
win = tk.Tk()
screen = Frame(win)
setting = Frame(win)
start = Frame(win)
'''for frame in (screen,setting,start):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
    '''
#def change_walk():
    #setting.pack(fill='both',expand=1)
    #screen.pack_forget()
#def change_setting():
    #screen.pack(fill='both',expand=1)
    #setting.pack_forget()
#class counting (self):
win.title('applied_computing')
'''win.configure(background='pink')'''
#sizing the screen
win.minsize()
win.maxsize(450,400)
win.geometry('1366x768')
for frame in (screen,setting,start):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
#for the counting 



#buttons/input
#button 1 button to interact with things on screen
button = tk.Button(screen,text=('interact'),background='pink', width=10,height=5,wraplength=50)
button.config(height=5 ,width=5)
button.place(x=0,y=200)
button.pack()
#button 2 the buttin to go back
button2 = tk.Button(screen,text=('back'),background='pink', width=10,height=5,wraplength=39, command = raise_frame(start))
button2.config(height=5 ,width=5)
button2.place(x=0,y=100)
button2.pack()
#button 3 button to stimulate stepping
button3 = tk.Button(screen,text=('STEP'),background='pink', width=10,height=5, wraplength=10,command= clicked)
button3.config(height=5 ,width=5)
button3.place(x=405,y=150)
button3.pack()
#label/ screen for infomation for counting steps
screen = tk.Label(screen,width=50,height=25,text=('steps=',steps))
screen.place(x=50,y=10)
screen.pack()



#running the screen
button = tk.Button(start,text=('interact'),background='pink', width=10,height=5,wraplength=50)
button.config(height=5 ,width=5)
button.place(x=0,y=200)
button.pack()
#button 2 the buttin to go back
button2 = tk.Button(start,text=('back'),background='pink', width=10,height=5,wraplength=39,command = raise_frame(start))
button2.config(height=5 ,width=5)
button2.place(x=0,y=100)
button2.pack()
#button 3 button to stimulate stepping
button3 = tk.Button(start,text=('STEP'),background='pink', width=10,height=5, wraplength=10,command= raise_frame(screen))
button3.config(height=5 ,width=5)
button3.place(x=405,y=150)
button3.pack()



#running the screen
button = tk.Button(setting,text=('interact'),background='pink', width=10,height=5,wraplength=50)
button.config(height=5 ,width=5)
button.place(x=0,y=200)
button.pack()
#button 2 the buttin to go back
button2 = tk.Button(setting,text=('back'),background='pink', width=10,height=5,wraplength=39,command = raise_frame(start))
button2.config(height=5 ,width=5)
button2.place(x=0,y=100)
button2.pack()
#button 3 button to stimulate stepping
button3 = tk.Button(setting,text=('STEP'),background='pink', width=10,height=5, wraplength=10,command= raise_frame(screen))
button3.config(height=5 ,width=5)
button3.place(x=405,y=150)
button3.pack()

raise_frame(screen)
win.mainloop()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBB2Q.png)

Comment: Why are you using both screen.place(x=50,y=10)
screen.pack()?

Comment: Also why are you duplicated button. Also why both button.place(x=0,y=200)
button.pack()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok there's a couple of things that we can work on here, but I'm going to focus on your "screen swapping" first.  Note that this is a way to do it without really thinking about classes or any of that, and probably is not the best way to solve this, but as you are new to Python and tkinter, I think this will work perfectly fine in your application.  Usually what I like to do is create a main frame to hold everything in my tkinter application if I want to be able to swap screens.  Then what I do is write a small function to clear all widgets from a frame like this:

```
# Public method clearFrame
# Arguments:
#   - frame: The given frame that needs to be cleared.
# 
# Clear every widget from the frame passed in.
# Window will remain open, assure you fill with something afterwards.

def clearFrame(frame):
    for widgets in frame.winfo_children():
        widgets.destroy()
```

Then when I want to switch "screens" which is more really just clearing the screen and loading new stuff, I will set a button with a command that will clear the frame, and populate it with something else. So it would look like this:

```
root = tk.Tk()
mainFrame = tk.Frame(root)

backPageButton = tk.Button(root, text="Last Page", command=lastPage)
nextPageButton = tk.Button(root, text="Next Page", command=nextPage)

def nextPage():
   clearFrame(mainFrame)
   populateSecondPage() # A function that contains all the widgets for the second page

def lastPage():
   clearFrame(mainFrame)
   populateFirstPage() # A function that contains all the widgets for the first page
```

The `populateFirstPage()` function can contain your widgets for the first page, and then the `populateSecondPage()` function can contain your widgets for the settings screen for example.  I hope that this makes sense and I would be happy to answer some questions if you have them.

A few more notes:
You are using multiple geometry managers at the same time: `place()` and then `pack()`.  You only need to use one or the other.  By calling `pack()` right after `place()` you are overwriting everything from the `place()` function, so there is no point in using it.

You are also setting the height and width of a button, and then immediately configuring it to a different height and width right after declaration.  Why? Just set it to what you want initially.

As for understanding classes and init, w3schools is a fantastic resource for a beginner, and will explain to you and give you examples of code in different languages.  This page [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) will show you how to create classes and what the `init` function is.  For when you begin to understand that, here is a good example to help you start creating these pages more efficiently using classes: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tkinter-application-to-switch-between-different-page-frames/

Good luck! :)